# Javascript, while loop return

Tags: javascript, while-loop, return

```
var i = 0;
while(i < 100){
   return "The number is " + i;
   i++;
}
```

What is wrong with my return statement? Why can I return a string plus a variable?

Comment: Is this all of your JS code? The `return` statement needs to be inside a function. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: Having a `return` statement directly inside a `while` loop will result in only one iteration being executed. (It makes your loop useless). However, if you replace this line with something like `console.log(i);`, it should print 0, 1, ..., 99 to the console.

Comment: @blex And if you put the return statement before the end of the loop, it will result in less than one iteration being executed. Making it even more useless.

Comment: Replace `return "the number is " + i` with `console.log("the number is " + i)`, press F12, choose the "console" tab, press F5 (assuming that your code is embedded into a web page).

Comment: Thanks, I will use console.log()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`return` means end of function and return some value. Any statements after return statement will not be executed and the execution of a function will terminate at return statement. So, `return` in your case will make the loop to execute only one and terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code should be inside a function.
Secondly the return statement which u have written inside the for loop will execute the result only once and it will come out of the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with this text, but `return` will take you out of the function. If you want to display this text, you could use `<div id="demo">` and then use the function to create text inside of it like this:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < 100){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<p>The number is " + i + "</p>";
    i++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmerzbacher/fdu7aauz/