# Javascript while loop not running till condition is satisifed in appium+wd.js

Tags: javascript, android, mocha.js, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to count the total elements of a **recycler view** in **android appium using wd.js.**

For this I am using the logic:

1.For the id get all elements displayed on the screen>>get each elements unique content description and save it to an array.

2.Swipe/scroll the screen >>save the element's unique attribute to the array>>while total length of the array is not equal to the total count

I have written below code for this:

```
it("Scroll and save offerid to offersPresent List", function () {
  while(offersPresent.length !== offersCount) {
     return  offersPOM.swipeNew(driver, function (err, res) { }).then(function () {
           driver.elementsById('someId').then(function (els) {
               els.forEach(function (el) {
                   el.getAttribute('contentDescription').then(function (offerId) {
                      //Here I check if the offerId is already there in the array or not
                       if (offersPresent.indexOf(offerId) === -1) {
                           offersPresent.push(offerId);
                       }
                       console.log('offersPresent'.green, offersPresent);
                   })
               })

           })
       })
   }
 });
```

The swipNew function is:

```
exports.swipeNew = function (driver, callback) {
 var action = new TouchAction(driver);
  action
   .press({ x: 17, y: 1500 })
   .wait(2000)
   .moveTo({ x: 17, y: 254 })
   .release();
 return action.perform().then(function (err, res) {
   return callback(err, res);
 })
};
```

**The problem is no matter the condition, this loop only runs once.**
How to make this loop run till the while condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

The return function in Javascript will stop the while loop so it will only attempt the code in the while loop once.

Here is a another question that explains it in more detail:  [Javascript, while loop return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170943/javascript-while-loop-return)